# How can I post on my facebook timeline programatically?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-timeline

I want to publish a story on my timeline.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do this is to read the following:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

From the above:

The following example uses the FB.ui() method to invoke the Feed Dialog to allow a user to post a link to their timeline:

```
FB.ui(
{
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
},

function(response) 
{
    if (response && response.post_id) 
    {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } 
    else 
    {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
 }
```

);